# Show only category once

Tags: mysql, group-by, categories

Let's say I have a list of cars. I only want to show the name of the cars once in a list of all cars. Let's say it should look like this:

```
**Jaguar**
XK8
XR
XF

**Audi**
A8
A4
A5
```

How do I categorize them?.
I'm using a simple mysql call like:

```
$lists = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM products INNER JOIN cats ON cat_id=product_cat GROUP BY product_cat");
while($listdata = $lists->fetch_assoc()){}
```

Comment: Add some sample input data and output data

Answer (score 1):

Add the names to a new array.

```
$allcars = $mysqli->query("SELECT car_name, car_id, car_descr, car_type FROM cats"); 
$namelist = array();
while($carsdata = $allcars->fetch_assoc()){ $namelist[] = $carsdata['car_type']; }
```

Comment: does this also works in a inner join, i just edited my question, sry :-)